# No me muestra la imagen que subo en imageview

Tags: android, android-imageview

Lo que pasa es que quiero que aparezca la imagen que selecciono de mi galería en un `imageview` dentro de android.

Código de tipo  `onActivityResult`:

```
 @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            View view= inflate.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_manual, viewgroup, false);

            if (resultCode == -1) {
                if (requestCode == 111) {

                    Uri uri = data.getData();
                    try {
                        InputStream stream = getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                        ImageView iv = view.findViewById(R.id.imgImage);
                        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }

        }
```

Evento de `listener` y donde se aloja el evento click del **button** de subida.

```
btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {


        Intent intent=new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        startActivityForResult(intent,111);



    }

});
```

Actualmente no se muestra nada en el `imageview` y **se queda en blanco**.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando obtienes el bitmap y agregas este a tu `ImageView` mediante el método `setImageBitmap()`, posteriormente agregas la imagen `ic_launcher_foreground` a tu ImageView, por esta razón no se muestra la imagen que obtienes de la galería:

```
  InputStream stream = getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
  ImageView iv = view.findViewById(R.id.imgImage);
  iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);  //Agrega imagen.
  iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground); //Agrega nuevamente imagen.
```

te recomiendo agregar la imagen ic_launcher_foreground únicamente si no pudiste obtener el bitmap:

```
            try {
                InputStream stream = getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
                ImageView iv = view.findViewById(R.id.imgImage);

                if(bitmap != null){
                   iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }else{
                   iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);
                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```